# why MySLQ datadir must be owned by mysql user?

Tags: mysql, installation

I read this from MySQL document:

> Otherwise, most of the MySQL installation can be owned by root if you like. The exception is that the data directory **must be owned by mysql**.

- Can somebody tell me why?
- Why data directory owned by root is not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MySQL is running, it runs as the mysql user account. If the data directory was owned by root, MySQL would not have permission to write to it!